# I can't change static void Main(string[] args)

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [i cant change static void Main(string[] args)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5646863/i-cant-change-static-void-mainstring-args)

Hi,
when I change  static void Main(string[] args) to this code
the error I get is

Program 'C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Project1\FtpFiles\FtpFiles\obj\Debug\FtpFiles.exe' does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point
Can anyone please help me?

Comment: That's right, you should not change it. If you'll explain **why** you need to change it we might be able to show you some correct way.

Comment: You writing a console app? Main has a limited set of acceptable signatures because it is the default entry point for applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot change the "static void Main(string[] args)" name or argument, it is the entry point for the program.

If you don't want the args[] parameter, just ignore it.

Answer (score 2):

You need a `static void Main` method in every program, this is called an entry point, meaning this is what the runtime looks for when trying to execute your program. If there is none, it fails, as you saw with your example.

Answer (score 0):

check this post : [Entry Point in C# program](http://www.csharphelp.com/2006/08/entry-point-in-c-program/)

```
static void Main(string[] args) - 
 is palce from where you code get started executing.
```

if its not found it will give an error to you.

if you dont want to use if than create >> class Library project rather than console application.

Comment: can you please say me how to jump to another code in console application

Comment: for examplestatic void Main(string[] args)

Comment: by creating object of the class and calling its method...from main